# A table row hover state is not removed until the transform transition has ended in Chrome

Tags: css, hover, transition, tablerow

I have a hover transform transition applied to a table row. When you hover off it the child table cells seem to keep the hover state until the transform transition has ended. It only seems to happen in Chrome.

```css
table {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
.summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform linear .3s;
  transition: transform linear 0.5s;
}
.summary td {
  background: #fff;
}
.summary:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.03);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.03);
    transform:scale(1.03);
}
.summary:hover td {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1795EA;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="summary">
   <td>897689789789</td>
   <td>username</td>
   <td>2323233</td>
   <td>name@address.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="summary">
   <td>897689789789</td>
   <td>username</td>
   <td>2323233</td>
   <td>name@address.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="summary">
   <td>897689789789</td>
   <td>username</td>
   <td>2323233</td>
   <td>name@address.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a quirk of Chrome's implementation of `scale`? I've seen other questions where `scale` causes elements to behave differently than expected.